# Want a common EnterpriseLibrary for .NET Core MVC (common database file)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, enterprise-library

Currently, I am learning .NET Core and updated my site from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC.

In ASP.NET MVC, I used `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary` for handling the database related tasks. But when I used this library in .NET Core, I got this error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.IsTransient(Exception ex)

Can anyone help me to get the example of all types of SQL operations with Enterprise Library and `RetryPolicy`? I want to create a database common file from where I can do all SQL operation

Comment: I'd recommend just using Entity Framework Core for your database requirements. It can do just about anything you'll need and is built for .NET Core and well supported. I'm not familiar with the Enterprise Library but I did a quick search on it and it appears it is not well supported for .NET Core. You'd probably have to find piece parts of the library that have been ported from .NET Framework 4.5 for use in .NET Core. I would suggest the EF Core option.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But I want to use ADO.net so for that want a common base class for all operation of the database.